# How to enable a button after loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to disable a button when the page is loading.

How do I enable the button after fully loading the page, using jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Disable any button from the beginning:

```
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" />
```

And add the enable to window ready function

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("input[type=button]", "<input[type=submit]", "input[type=reset]").each( //add more selector here if you want
            function(){
                if($(this).attr("disabled"))
                    $(this).attr("disabled", false); //enable button again
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(window).load ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do

```
<body onload="load()">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
        document.getElementById("buttonID").disabled=true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a disabled property for the button and in the script, document ready function remove disabled function.

```
$("#buttonID").prop('disabled',false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [@Bang Dao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438157/3935089) but using native JavaScript.

Disable the button from the beginning:

```
<button id="button" disabled>A button</button>
```

And then listen for the `DOMContentLoaded` event on `document`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.disabled = false;
});
```